# What is the best strategy on playing Defensive Roman on Travian 4?

Tags: travian

there are many options to play on Travian, I like defensive, I believe defensive strategy cost less and is more effective in End Game Era, but I wonder how is the step by step manual?

Comment: IS your question about Travian, or Travian 4?

Comment: I tried that my question show what I mean

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? Can you please be a bit more specific? No one is going to write a step by step manual here on how to play from the first day till the end game.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sim fields/make enough praetorians/level wall to dissuade attack.
2. Sim more fields and make more praetorians.  Continue building new villages and making praetorians until the game ends.

Comment: I made account just to comment on your answer, which is entirely WRONG. You do need a large number of troops, but you need troops with 20 lv armory and 20 lv arena, since Praetorians are so slow. So 6-8 defensive villages around your capital or next to the capital of the attackers in the alliance is highly more efficient since you want to keep your troops production 24/7 in all of them and you reach your crop limit pretty fast anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of really many factors. Every tribe have good things and weaknesses.
If you choose Guals:

- At the beginning traps. (no one will attack Gual because of that)
- After that Phalanx and Druidrider.

Since you can train defence in all villages, just making new villages and train defence.

After some time, and you have good number of defence, you can start upgrading your troops. Troops defence will be upgraded no meter when they was trained, so after some time you will be an advantage because you have higher number of updated troops.